# Cannot programatically select from RadComboBox when EnableAutomaticLoadOnDemand is enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am no longer able to programatically set a selection for a Telerik RadComboBox after having set [EnableAutomaticLoadOnDemand](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/load-on-demand/automatic-load-on-demand) to true. When it is set to false, I can. I suspect that because the items haven't been loaded into the ComboBox before the user types in it that the ComboBox doesn't have any reference to the Text/Value/Index that is being selected. Here is my situation:

On page load, I want a RadComboBox item to be selected based on a variable:

```
int userID = 1;
RadComboBox1.SelectedValue = userID.ToString();
```

When setting a breakpoint at runtime, userID has a value, but RadComboBox1.SelectedValue stays unassigned as "".

The RadComboBox's datasource is an ObjectDataSource with Text and Value fields set appropriately. Is there a reason why turning on Automatic Load-On-Demand would prevent the RadComboBox's selection to be assigned?

My aspx looks like this:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="RadComboBox1" DataTextField="SomeName" DataValueField="SomeID" Filter="Contains" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" ShowMoreResultsBox="True" EnableAutomaticLoadOnDemand="True">
    <Items><telerik:RadComboBoxItem/></Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="RadComboBox1" 
    DataTextField="SomeName" DataValueField="SomeID" 
    Filter="Contains" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" 
    AutoPostBack="True" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    ShowMoreResultsBox="True" 
    EnableAutomaticLoadOnDemand="True">
</telerik:RadComboBox>


if(RadComboBox1.Items.FindItemByValue(userID.ToString()) != null)
    RadComboBox1.Items.FindItemByValue(userID.ToString()).Selected = true;
```